# Are transition strips necessary in doorway for same level tile to tile?

Tags: tile, transition

I removed the carpet in a room and now I am installing wood like ceramic tile. There is existing 12" by 12" ceramic tile in the hallway. Both Tiles are the same level. The wood-like is light brown and the existing ceramic in the hallway is beige.  Should I put a transition strip in the doorway or just join both tiles at the doorway where the carpet used to end.

Comment: it's easier to get get acceptable results with a transition. they can help hide seasonal expansion/contraction issues as well.

Answer (score 3):

There is no right or wrong answer to this as it depends on personal preference.

If it were me I would strongly consider *not* using a transition strip, to remove an additional element which would require extra work to install and maintain. A simple grout joint between the two tile types would probably be fine.

Comment: Totally agree. My only suggestion would be to make sure the  corners of the tiles butting up against each other are sanded smooth.